# Pronouncing J's

Tags: pronunciation

I don't know very much about Italian, but I was trying to learn a bit, and I came across Jesolo- I was wondering how J's get treated in Italian. I know they aren't native Italian letters, but I can't find how they are pronounced-sites are saying that "Jesolo" is read like "Yesolo" so are all j's pronounced like y's in English?

Comment: What do you mean by “they aren't native Italian letters”? J was a variant form of I in Latin and later in Italian, and used later specifically as a semivowel (the “y” sound you are referring to) since 16th century (see [Treccani article on letter J](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/j-j/)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Italian "j" is pronounced like a semi consonant "i" when it occurs between vowels or at the beginning of a word (e.g. "Ajaccio", "Jacopo"); otherwise it is pronounced like an "i" when it occurs at the end of a word, typically as the plural of some words ending in "-io" ("varj", plural of "vario") ([1](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/j/), [2](http://forum.accademiadellacrusca.it/forum_10/interventi/4737.shtml.html)).

As Rmano pointed out, an alternative to "j" for the plural of some words ending in "-io" is [circumflex "î"](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/plurale-dei-nomi-in-io_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/). The use of "j" is more ancient than "î" but today they are both not much in use anymore (anyway, I still like the use of "î", I think it is still considered erudite Italian and it still has its function).

Note that Italian "y" is pronounced just as "i" ([3](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/y/)).

Comment: Da italiano - d'accordo su tutto ma non ho veramente mai visto `varj`. Mi avevano insegnato a usare semplicemente   `vari` o al limite ad aggiungere un circonflesso `varî`. Buono a sapersi, comunque.

Comment: @Rmano: “Vari” è il plurale di “varo” (detto di una nave). :-)

Comment: @DaG --- ;-) lo so (per fortuna anche dopo 16 anni fuori)... avevo visto `-î`, `-ii` e usare semplicemente `-i` e lasciare che il contesto facesse il resto. È la prima volta che vedo `-j`!

Comment: @Rmano: Non dubitavo che lo sapessi. Confermo ogni tua parola: le forme in -ii e in -î sarebbero quelle corrette, ma di fatto si usa quasi sempre quella in -i, mentre quella in -j o addirittura in -ij è davvero desueta.

Comment: Nella risposta non c'è scritto che, anche in accordo all'articolo citato sul Treccani "j" si trova pronunciata come "g", e.g., in alcuni termini utilizzati come Joker, Jolly, Jack, Jessica. Pronuncia dal ramo francese pesanemente ereditata nei termini anglofoni.